# Как показать значение в DBLookupComboBox?

Tags: delphi

Как показать выбранное значение в `DBLookupComboBox`? При условие если в одной форме выбирается значение в одном `DBLookupComboBox`, то значение в первом `DBLookupComboBox`, на другой форме, должно тоже меняться.

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте обработчик на изменение, а в нем пропишите:

```
  if DBLookupComboBox1.Focused then
    DBLookupComboBox2.KeyValue := DBLookupComboBox1.KeyValue;
```

А для второго:

```
  if DBLookupComboBox2.Focused then
    DBLookupComboBox1.KeyValue := DBLookupComboBox2.KeyValue;
```

`Focused` проверка на то, что именно пользователь сейчас меняет значение в конкретном контроле, а не обработчик.

Answer (score 1):

Если оба `DBLookupComboBox` и на одной, и на другой форме связаны с одной и той же таблицей (здесь я имею ввиду компонент `TTable` или `TADOTable`), то данные и там, и там должны меняться автоматически. Если в программе много форм, то хорошо пользоваться модулем данных: накидать все невизуальные компоненты для работы с БД туда, и подключить его ко всем требуемым формам. Главное - связать `DBLookupComboBox` на каждой форме с одной таблицей, тогда и кода писать не придётся, и данные будут автоматически меняться на обоих формах. Вот небольшой тестовый пример.
[image]

Comment: Думаю, что если бы оба DBLookupComboBox-а были бы связаны с одним DataSet-ом у человека вопрос бы не возник :)

А так, да, или дата-модуль или DataSet на главной форме...

Comment: Ну, не знаю. У моего однокурсника однажды подобный вопрос возник. Может быть потому, что он в Delphi приложений для работы с БД не писал.

Comment: Тут у меня всё на главной форме.

Comment: Согласен, вопрос, скорее всего, от неправильной архитектуры.

Answer (score 0):

Может просто связать датасет по MasterFields!?